# kmeans with sparse vectors in elki

Tags: java, k-means, outliers, elki

When i try this method with dense vectors data it's run correctly, but with sparse vectors data throws `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. What datasource can i use to read sparse vectors data correctly?

```
public void runKmeans(double[][] data) {
ArrayAdapterDatabaseConnection dataArray = new ArrayAdapterDatabaseConnection(data);

ListParameterization params = new ListParameterization();
params.addParameter(AbstractDatabase.Parameterizer.DATABASE_CONNECTION_ID, dataArray);

Database db = ClassGenericsUtil.parameterizeOrAbort(StaticArrayDatabase.class, params);
db.initialize();


// Parameterization
//params = new ListParameterization();
params = new ListParameterization();
params.addParameter(KMeans.K_ID, k);
params.addParameter(KMeans.SEED_ID, 0);


// setup Algorithm
KMeansOutlierDetection<DoubleVector> kmeansAlg = ClassGenericsUtil.parameterizeOrAbort(KMeansOutlierDetection.class, params);
//testParameterizationOk(params);

// run KMEANS on database
OutlierResult result = kmeansAlg.run(db);
...
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `ArrayAdapterDatabaseConnection` only supports *dense* data. `DoubleVector` also is a *dense* data type. Any chance you misinterpreted the format of `data`?

Comment: Apart from that, K-means does not make *sense* on sparse data. Whatever you are trying to do - it is the wrong algorithm.

Comment: I' ve first used ArrayList to read, and so,  i' ve used toArray method to populate it.  I've tried to use kmeans because when i use Elki's Gui, Kmeans can run my sparse data in arff format. Why by Elki's Gui can Kmeans  run but by code cannot

Comment: Of course you can code that, but these classes *don't* do that. A `double[]` is a *dense* format. You can build your own data source, or use the Arff data source, or, or, or, ... but in the end, k-means assumes dense data from a *theoretical* point of view.

Comment: How would you meaningfully put a *sparse* vector in that ArrayList?

Comment: I read incrementaly a arff sparse file like this  `@data
    {1 X, 3 Y, 4 "class A"}
    {2 W, 4 "class B"}`, and so, i use `arrlist.add(data)`. When stop reading, i do
`inputMatrix = new double[arrlist.size()][arrlist.get(0).length];
inputMatrix = arrlist.toArray(inputMatrix);`

i do this beacause in my program i can't read directly arff file , i need to read it incrementaly.

Comment: To explain why **k-means does not make sense on sparse data**: k-means uses the *mean*. It assumes a fixed dimensionality d, too. Averaging sparse vectors of different length destoys all the nice mathematic support for the algorithm.

Comment: And how do you *store* that data in a `double[]`? Why don't you put all that code into the question? Also, it looks like categorial data, k-means requires continuous data.

Comment: it was just a example. My data is really continuous data. i declare inputMatrix as double[][]. After store it, i call `runKmeans(inputMatrix);`

Comment: i agree kmeans doesn't make sense for sparse data. I just think strange Elki's Gui can run arff sparse file without throw java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException too.

Comment: But `double[][]` is *dense*, and you wanted *sparse* data! Whatever you are doing (add the preparation code to your question, please), you are *not* creating sparse vectors.

Comment: Also, the way you seem to initialize it (with `toArray`) makes it likely non-square (because of ragged arrays). Maybe this is causing the error. Verify that *all* rows have the same length (but again, this is a *dense* format that you are using).

Comment: rows doesn't have same length. So, are you trying tell me i need to use something like `SparseDoubleVector` from Elki to store sparse data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class [`ArrayAdapterDatabaseConnection`](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/releases/release0.7.0/doc/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/datasource/ArrayAdapterDatabaseConnection.html) can *only* be used for *dense* vectors. You must supply a *square* `double[][]` array.

You can use `FileBasedDatabaseConnection` and the `ArffParser` to read sparse data. Or you can implement your own [`DatabaseConnection`](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/releases/release0.7.0/doc/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/datasource/DatabaseConnection.html), it is a single method only, `loadData()`.

[`DoubleVector`](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/releases/release0.7.0/doc/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/data/DoubleVector.html) is a *dense* data type. [`SparseDoubleVector`](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/releases/release0.7.0/doc/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/data/SparseDoubleVector.html) is a sparse vector type. To do this, `DoubleVector` is backed using a dense `double[]` array, whereas `SparseDoubleVector` uses a `int[]` with the nonzero dimensions, plus a `double[]` with the nonzero values *only*.

K-means *requires* a fixed dimensionality to allocate the mean vectors (these will always be dense), so make sure to supply a `VectorFieldTypeInformation` with the maximum dimensionality. There is a type conversion filter that simply scans you data set once, and sets the dimension accordingly.